# How hot can a lithium ion battery safely get while charging?

Tags: temperature, safety, lithium-ion, charging

How hot can a lithium ion battery safely get while charging?  I've found some [references to 113F](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_at_high_and_low_temperatures), but I know a lot of batteries used in cell phones get a *lot* hotter than 113F.  I measured 140F on my Galaxy S4 while it was charging up from a fully discharged battery.  On the other hand, Samsung is currently exploding batteries with their Note 7, so cell phone manufactures may not be the best reference.

Is 113F the max *ambient* temperature for charging lithium ion batteries?  In that case, what's the recommended max temperature for a battery pack itself?

Comment: See the datasheet.

Comment: Agreed.  This type of question is best answered on an individual bases.   Also, this is probably one of those occasions where you might be better off using a reputable manufacturer.

Comment: Also keep in mind that in a mobile phone or tablet there are chips that can (somewhat) easily reach 90degC, so the temperature you measure outside might not be entirely related to the battery. And please use SI units since the majority of people is not from the US, Burma or Liberia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not good/bad, probably that 113 F (45 C) is probably on the conservative and safe side.

Being able to charge a phone quickly is a **selling point** so Samsung probably deliberately allows for a higher temperature before the charging rate is decreased.

A higher temperature decreases the lifetime of the battery.

Samsung choose **their** optimum balance between battery charging time, safety and lifetime.

Your choice might be different dependent on the application. If a long charging time is not an issue then that 113 F is probably fine.

And as mentioned in the comments: read the datasheet

Comment: Not so optimum,  unless they intended to sell grenades lol